# Video does not Play again after navigation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2, html5-video

I have code written in Ionic2.
Whnen first i come to video page the video play, then i navigate to home page again navigate to video page video does not get play, and video element is present.
Any help would be appreciated.
Below is code:

```
     <video width="320" height="240" controls id="videoTag">
  </video>

    export class VideoPage implements OnInit {
        ngOnInit() {
            this.userId = this.user.userId;
            this.playVideo("abc.mp4");
        }
        playVideo(src){
            var vid = document.getElementById('videoTag');
            vid.setAttribute("src", src);
            vid.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
            vid.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");
        }
        onHome(){
            this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
        }

    }
```

First time when ngOnInit gets called video gets played, then when i press home button it gets navigated to home page then again when videopage is loaded onNgInit gets called but video is not played.